# PHP: meaning of 'thing' with two uses of ->

Tags: php, methods, properties

> Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

What does it mean when you have something like this `$this->_view->id` ?

It is within a class (obviously) and I understand the $this. I get how to use one -> to refer to a property or call a method. But what about when there are two -> in one thing?

The fuller code is:

```
$viewid = ($this->_view) ? $this->_view->id : null;
```

I'm guessing the overall gist is: Set `$viewid` to either (1) the value of `$this->_view->id` or (2) null, depending on whether `$this->_view` is TRUE or not. But I don't get the (1) bit.

Also, is it conventional to use an underscore (_view) to show a property or a method?

Thanks.

Comment: The underscore usually denotes that a member variable or a method is private. Not everybody follows this however.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: The Reference info on the symbol doesn't go into multiple uses of -> in one entity, @vascowhite, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that there is an object stored within an object.

$this->_view refers to an object called $_view within. So within $_view object $this->id would refer to its $id variable.

So calling $this->_view->id calls for variable $id in an object $_view that is stored in your current object (since you said its $this).

Detailed:

```
class firstClass {
    public $_view;
}
class secondClass{
    public $id=1;
}
$a=new firstClass();
$a->_view=new secondClass();
echo $a->_view->id; // prints 1
```

Comment: Umm... I'm still thinking here, @kristovaher.  At the top of the class it says var $_view = null;   Further down the code it has: if ($this->_view) {return $this->_view->getValue('name');  So in this case, getValue has to be a method, right? I'm confident your way works. But can you have $this=object->_view=property->getValue()=method? If so, id still can't be a method because there is no (), right? So could it be $this=object->_view=property->id=property ? Surely not. I'm still confused, I'm afraid.

Comment: At the top of the class it simply says that $_view is undefined at first. Look for when anything is assigned to $_view. Note that based on how complicated (or how badly) code is written, $_view may also be assigned dynamically someplace (such as through a Factory pattern), making debugging more difficult.

Comment: Yes, I see now. Declaring it with the var $.. = null; is a trap for young (read: noob) players, though! Thanks, again.

Answer (score 1):

`$viewid = ($this->_view) ? $this->_view->id : null;`

It means if view object is available for current object, then set its id to $viewid, otherwise set it to null.

for example `$this` is current object of `UserClass`. `$this->_view` is object of view of UserClass and `$this->_view->id` is id of view object.

Generally, for private or protected member of class, we start with `_`

Answer (score 0):

`$id` is attached to an object returned by the function `function _view`.

The underscore is a preference,

Comment: I think that kristovaher is right, @thenetimp. _view is an object, not a function/method! Thanks, though.